# Empty "List View Button Layout" for the Quote object?

Tags: list-view, quote

I have more problems with quotes today (in a different question), and as I was examining it, I saw this:

[image]

This is not normal, is it? Every other object that I checked has something here. It is not possible for me to accidentally delete it, as an admin I can only edit this, not delete it.

Does anybody else experience this? How can I get the object back that used to be here? I have already logged a case with Salesforce Support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be a case of Works As Designed. Unfortunately quote list view aren't available on quote object.

Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000KtkV3UAJ/allow-adding-buttons-and-quick-actions-to-quote-list-views) and upvote.